# How to work with volume when I have more than one mediaPlayer running

Tags: android, media-player

If I've more than one mediaPlayer (created by `MediaPlayer.create(...)`) running at same time in loop, how I can get the current volume of **just one** of them? And how I can change the volume also of **just one** of them?

I'm trying to use a seekBar to modify the volume of a single player, however every time that I tried to get the current volume of a single player by `audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` the volume always return 100% (this way the seekBar progress do not corresponds to the real volume), and I also found nothing about how to get the current volume using the own mediaPlayer, just using audioManage, has a way of do this using the own mediaPlayer? (not using audioManage).

And also every time that I tried to change the current volume of a single player by

```
float finalVolume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(100 - progress) / Math.log(100)));
mp.setVolume(finalV, finalV);
```

this just worked for a few seconds, after a little while the volume back to normal again. How I fix this?

**NOTE** - progress in Math.log(...) above is the progress retrieved of seekBar

Thanks...